# cms and newsletter preserving formatting

Tags: cms, backend, newsletter

we use html code view to enter templates in Magento through the CMS. Everytime we do this, we notice that after saving all formatting is lost. making it difficult to read back what we made (and rather useless).

For example, we enter:

```
<div style="color: black; display: block; font: 12px Verdana, Arial; padding: 20px; background: whitesmoke;">
<div style="display: block; background: white; border: 1px solid #bebcb7; padding: 8px;">

<!-- Header plaatje --> 
<div><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" /></div>

<!-- Introductie tekst -->
<div><p>Goedendag {{var customer_name}}, <br /><br />
```

and it ends up like

```
<div style="color: black; display: block; font: 12px Verdana, Arial; padding: 20px; background: whitesmoke;"><div style="display: block; background: white; border: 1px solid #bebcb7; padding: 8px;"><!-- Header plaatje --> <div><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" /></div><!-- Introductie tekst --><div><p>Goedendag {{var customer_name}}, <br /><br />
```

all on one line.

Question: what can we do about this? Its a shame we loose all formatting

This is not what I would expect.

Also - isnt the CMS editor in Magento already quite old?

Thanks, Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not standard system behavior — I just copy pasted your test from here and everything came through fine.  It sounds like someone's added some customizations to your system that adds extra formatting to your CMS text.

Are the line breaks present if your view source and find the TinyMCE text editor?  If so, then someone's changed your TinyMCE initialization in Magento, or possible the `./mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js` file.  Diff vs. a fresh version of Magento.

If the line breaks are remove even from the textarea, then the problem is a core change and/or custom module.  Again, diff vs. a fresh version of Magento to determine why this happened.